# How to load picture from web into webview?

Tags: java, android, html, json, webview

I wanna load picture from web or url address like : `
"https://images.detik.com/community/media/visual/2017/11/03/5e88c080-0570-47ca-8ea9-96209df2071d_169.jpeg?w=620"

But it cannot open or load as well.

here i capture the result :
[image]

What a code to make it works, please help thank you.

here my code

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainbackdrop);

//BIND
nameTxt.setText(name);
propTxt.setText(propellant);
wv.loadData(desc, "text/html","UTF-8");
PicassoClient.downloadImage(this,imageurl,img);
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @RatilalChopda i don't think this comment is related with post

Comment: Again @RatilalChopda i don't think this comment is related with post

Comment: i've updated my question..

Comment: @RizkiDeddySusanto please check my answer.

Comment: What do you want exactly? You mess around with a webview and an imageview. Why? Pretty confusing. As you have it now the jpg has nothing to do with the webview. Your picture suggest that the html page contains a picture that cannot be found. Why post a problem so confusing?

Comment: What about the subject of your post? Is it that what you want? Then why messing around with an imageview and a html page?

Comment: @greenapps  i've update my picture in my question, green arrow is a imageview, the blue circle its indicated that i display text html, and the red circle is image url address.. my question is, why image url can not load as well?

Comment: Unclear. If the green arrow points to an imageview then it displays already an image. From url? Which url? And then you would have a second imageview below the webview? In which you cannot load an url?

Comment: Why are you messing around with a webview if you have troubles loading an image in an imageview?

Comment: i think youre really didnt get it.. my question is clear, i populated data from database with html format and display into webview

Comment: `.. my question is clear,` Aha.. But after an hour still nobody knows what you want and why you mess around with imageviews if you want to display a picture in a webview. You can use loadUrl() for that.

Comment: I repeat: `Your picture suggest that the html page contains a picture that cannot be found.`. You could comment on that. A shame you didnt already.

Comment: `i populated data from database ` ?? What is 'populating data from database'?

Comment: `and display into webview`. Unclear what you display in webview. And how.

Comment: "Your picture suggest that the html page contains a picture that cannot be found"..yes thats my problem. Do you have any suggest?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you rewrite this post. Explain what you want in a decent way and remove all talk and code about imageviews.

Comment: You should also post a little source text of your html page. Especially the used `<img src="......">`. Post as much as we need to test it.

Answer (score 2):

**`Picasso`** Load Image then try this

```
Picasso.with(activity)
            .load(path)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.thumbnail_placeholder)
            .resize(width,height)
            .into(imageView);
```

**`Webview`** Load image Then Try this my friend

```
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: @Nilu you are not understand wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  then your stack overflow 8500+ reputation is not correct

Comment: still cant get what i want

Comment: did you want to load image in imageview or webview

Comment: i wanna load a picture from url web into webview

Comment: i populated data from database with html format and display into webview